# Asp.Net Core Check Open Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Developing an Asp.Net Core WebAPI, I was wondering if there is a way to access all running Http-Requests, so that you can count them, stop them or wait for them to finish. I would like to acccess this data inside a Hosted Service.

Is there an existing Implementation, or do I need to implement it myself?

I thought about having a middleware, which controlls all requests, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Campinho I have created a custom Middleware which is counting up, when the Request is incoming and counting down when the Request finished.